# Can Microsoft Exchange 2010 Server Standard be place directly on the Internet?

Tags: exchange-2010, internet

I have a 2008 Windows 64 bit server on the Internet.  Can I install Exchange 2010 Standard on that server?  Is there any reason you can't put the Exchange server right on the Internet like that?

Comment: Can you install it on that server?  Yes.  Do you want to?  I'm not sure.  At the very least, you don't mention firewalls or anything like that, so I can think of at least one reason you don't want it "on the Internet like that".

Comment: I'm sorry but you are serious about setting up **any system** connected to the Internet then you need to think sensibly about what you're trying to achieve instead of pulling statements like this from your, uh, ear and asking "is it true that you can..." all the time. And if you want our help with it, you should probably discuss your needs and requirements properly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure you can. You just need to follow [Configure Internet Mail Flow Directly Through a Hub Transport Server](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb738138.aspx) on TechNet to get this running, but it's simply a matter of creating a send connector to the internet and tweaking the default receive connector.

Microsoft have this to say in the same article I linked above, but provided you take sensible precautions and don't do something stupid I don't agree with it 100%. Sure, in an ideal world everyone would have an Edge transport server, but the internet facing Hub Transport server works very well in my personal experience.

> We don't recommend this topology because it increases security risks by exposing to the Internet the Exchange 2010 server and all roles installed on that server.

It goes without saying that you should have a firewall between your Exchange server and the internet with only the necessary holes poked into it, with default deny rules and such. As with any internet facing server, deploy Microsoft Updates as soon as is practically possible to mitigate any risks using that attack vector.

Depending on your paranoia and needs, you might also want to disable some mailbox features such as ActiveSync or OWA for everybody (`Get-Mailbox | Set-CASMailbox -ActiveSyncEnabled $False -OWAEnabled $False`). POP and IMAP are disabled out of the box, but if you choose to enable those features, consider only enabling the users that need it.

Comment: Thank you for answering me and not telling me not to do things.  Some people do not have the option of hosting or other solutions and must learn to do things.  We have a firewall and it is well maintained.

Answer (score 2):

Depends if you value your security.

If you put any kind of Windows server straight on the internet, you will lose control of it.  I think the going time these days for new servers is about 4 hours, but it could be less.

You'll need some kind of comprehensive firewall, and an IDS, amongst other changes to security practices to ensure that your mailserver stays safe, and free from malware.  Not to mention so that it doesn't get abused as an open relay.

Seriously, as I said before.  Find a Hosted Exchange solution.  This is not really a task for someone new to the whole sysadmin milieu